# ProgressBar won't be in Holo style

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-styles

I added a `ProgressBar` to my UI by using the ADT's visual editor. For some reason, the `ProgressBar` is not in Holo style used by my `Activity`, it's just a grey line thought it is supposed to be in Holo style. As you can see below, I didn't touch any `ProgressBar`'s attributes in Activity's style:

```
     <style name="sMain" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/mTabAreaBackground</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
</style>
```

The Bar's XML:

```
      <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pbMyBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
```

Any explanation for this strange behavior?

Comment: did u set the theme of your application to Holo in the manifest ? :)

Comment: Is it Holo when you run it on yur device ?

Comment: yes, also CheckBoxes seem to be in Holo theme. However, inserting a ProgressBar in any of my Activities causes it to be just a grey line instead of blue Holo, I'm a bit confused

Comment: `"?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"` isnt there supposed to be a `@` instead of `?` ?? :)

Comment: I thought about that but it makes my bar a round one if I replace the `?` with an `@`

Comment: Maybe raise a bounty on this so you get a better answer?

Comment: Regarding `?` vs `@`, the docs say: Must be a reference to another resource, in the form "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form "?[package:][type:]name".  Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#progressBarStyleHorizontal

Answer (score 1):

A gray line *is* Holo style -- it just doesn't have any progress.  Try setting `android:progress="50"` and you'll see half of it fill up with blue.

And just to reiterate, setting `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"` is what you need to do to get 'holo style'.